# Live Smooth Streaming and Pre-Recorded Content Injection

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, live-streaming

I've been coming up to speed on Live Smooth Streaming using Microsoft's Open Source MMPPF (SMF) player and IIS Media Services 4.1.  I can stream live with no problem.

My question is how can I insert pre-recorded content (like a commercial or B-Roll) using MMPPF during a live broadcast event?

Comment: I may have found my own answer at this link [Smooth Streaming Client 2.0 Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee958035(v=vs.95).aspx).

Comment: It looks like the Smooth Streaming Element (SSME) is not the same as the MMPPF player. I need to do more research.

Comment: Sounds to me you are on the wrong end of the wire.  This is done in the server, not the client.

Comment: @hans- I know that I can do it on the front end with a video mixer. Are you saying that I should be pushing messages from the server to the clients? Can you post a link pointing me in the right direction? Much appreciated.

Comment: If you are using SMF there should be plugin for advertisements - I have never used it but you can give it a try.

Comment: Btw. Smooth streaming element is implementation of smooth streaming for Silverlight while SMF is a whole player using smooth streaming (and smooth streaming element) as one option for playback.

Comment: I decided to go the route of using the SSME element, the appropriate Events for that element as well as using full duplex communication to and from the Server to the Silverlight app.  @Ladislav Mrnka thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to use SSME element (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.media.smoothstreaming.smoothstreamingmediaelement(v=vs.95).aspx) and communicate via Full Duplex polling following this example(http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/pchandraker/http-duplex-messaging-in-silverlight-4/).